# Null Linq Values

Tags: c#, types, linq-to-xml, nullable

I cant get this to work. The State field is empty on certain occassions, I am trying to get the result to return "--" if it is empty, or doesn't exist.

```
var CusipFields = from c in xml.Descendants("LISTARRAY")
                                  orderby c.Element("ASKYIELD").Value descending
                                  select new BondData()
                                  {

                                      CUSIP = c.Element("CUSIP").Value,
                                      Description = (string)c.Element("ISSUER").Value,
                                      Maturity= c.Element("MATURITYDT").Value,
                                      AskYield = float.Parse(c.Element("ASKYIELD").Value),
                                      State = (string)c.Element("STATE").Value ?? "--"
                                  }
                                  ;
```

This just doesn't want to work. The error I am getting is:

NullReferenceException was unhandled. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I KNOW that it does not exist. I thought that putting `?? "--"` will return "--" if c.Element("STATE").Value is null.

I can resort to modifying the statement to:

```
var CusipFields = from c in xml.Descendants("LISTARRAY")
                                  orderby c.Element("ASKYIELD").Value descending
                                  select c;
foreach(var t in CusipFields)
{
   switch(t.name)
    {
    }
}
```

But I think that it is slower. And its not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
State = (string)c.Element("STATE") ?? "--"
```

instead of

```
 State = (string)c.Element("STATE").Value ?? "--"
```

My answer assumes, that your problem is, that the `STATE` element is missing, not empty. Please tell me, whether or not that fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain why it works in that manner? If I am passing the Element(c.element("STATE")) to State as null, compared to passing the elements value, which is also null, Why does this work?

Comment: Your XML data doesn't contain an element `STATE`. Because of that `c.Elemet("STATE")` will return `null`. And on that `null` instance, you are trying to access the property `Value`. That can't work.

Comment: Makes sense, and worked, I just was assuming that it would recognize null as null, regardless of if it was an object or a value of the object.

Comment: The `??` operator is working on the whole expression. But your expression can't be "evaluated", because it is causing a `NullReferenceException`, before the `??` even comes to play. That's 100 % normal behavior... Please be so kind and accept my answer by checking the check mark below the votes.

Comment: Be careful, this works only because casting this type of object to string actually returns it's value property.  It will not always be the case, sometimes you'll have to use the ?: syntax.

Comment: Please elaborate: In which case will this not be the case? `Descendants` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. `XElement.Element()` returns an `XElement` and `XElement` has an explicit conversion to string, which will return the `Value` property as a string

Comment: I wasn't being specific to Xml but more referring to the general situation of trying to access a null referenced object.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `c.Element("STATE")` is null, not it's Value property.

try:

`(string)c.Element("STATE") != null? (string)c.Element("STATE").Value : "--";`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error not because the `Value` property is null, but because `c.Element(...)` is null. You'll need to check for nulls in all of your `Element()` calls and take appropriate action in order to avoid this error.